# Lambda thread with IsBackground

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

When creating a new thread the regular way I can set the `IsBackground` like that

```
Thread t = new Thread(foo);
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start();
```

But how can I do it when running a lambda thread?

```
new Thread(() => {
    ...
}).Start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 new Thread(() =>
 { 
      // Do whatever
 })
 { IsBackground = true }.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    //
})
{ IsBackground = true }.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution should work:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => {
    ...
});
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start();
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.7.1#foreground-and-background-threads).